# Laravel user post not working

Tags: php, authentication, post, laravel

I'm having a problem while a user is trying to post a status update.

Here's the code of:

```
// Route

Route::post('/add', 'PostsController@postAdd');
```

//Post Model

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'posts';

protected $fillable = array('body', 'user_id');

public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

}
```

```
class PostsController extends BaseController {

    public function postAdd() {

        $user = Sentry::getUser();
        $body = array( 'body' => htmlspecialchars(Input::get('body'));
        $body['user_id'] = $user()->id;
        $post = new Post($body);
        $posts->save();
        return View::make('stream');
    }
}
```

//View

```
@extends('dashboard')

@section('content')
<div class="post-box">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="/add" method="POST" class="facebook-share-box">
        <div class="share">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Update Status</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                        <textarea required = "" name="body" cols="40" rows="10" id="body" class="form-control message" style="height: 62px; overflow: hidden;" placeholder="What's on your mind ?"></textarea>
                  </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-11">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Post</button>                              
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@stop
```

When the user updates the status:
The following message is displayed:
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
with the link stopped at http://localhost:8000/add.

Comment: What's your problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The post is not stored the view is not made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "Whoops" message is showing because an exception was thrown but your 'debug' configuration is set to false.  If you open your `app/config/app.php` file and set the `debug` key to true, you will be able to see the error being thrown. This should only be done in development, though; you don't want debug set to true in your production environment.

Having said that, it may be a typo in your question, but in your `postAdd` method, you have the code:

```
$post = new Post($body);
$posts->save();
```

but it should be:

```
$post = new Post($body);
$post->save(); // $post, not $posts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm still having the problem. It shows:Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @HammadAhmed That means you have a routing issue.  You're trying to POST to a GET route, or GET to a POST route.  From the code you've already shown, it looks like it should be working.  Your route is defined for a POST, and your form is defined to POST to the route, so there is something going on we can't see.  Can you update your question with a screenshot of the error now?

Comment: The SE editor says that you must have at least  10 rep to post an image. I've just signed up to post this question. You may have it here http://1drv.ms/1CmVY6c

Comment: @HammadAhmed No problem. That screenshot shows that you've made a GET request to the '/add' route. I'm assuming you did not define a Route to handle GET requests to the '/add' route (you've only shown a definition for POST).

Comment: `   public function dashboard() {

        $user = Sentry::getUser();
        return View::make('stream')->with('name', $user->email);
    }`

Comment: That's the get route.

Comment: @HammadAhmed But what about in your `routes.php`.  You showed us your `Route::post('/add', ...)` definition.  Do you have a `Route::get('/add', ...)` definition?

Comment: Thanks God! Just figured out that my form had been cluttered with the master view. Thanks for the support @patricus.

Comment: I just got another error.Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Function name must be a string
Open: D:\scripts\laravel\app\controllers\PostsController.php

    class PostsController extends BaseController {
     
    public function postAdd() {
     
    $user = Sentry::getUser();
    $body = array( 'body' => htmlspecialchars(Input::get('body')));
    $body['user_id'] = $user()->id;
    $post = new Post($body);
    $post->save();

Comment: @HammadAhmed Need another screenshot.

Comment: @HammadAhmed I don't know why that line is throwing that error.  What happens if you replace `$post = new Post($body); $post->save();` with `$post = Post::create($body);`?